# Typescript extended types declaration

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface x {
  a: string;
}

export interface y extends x {
  b: string;
}

export interface z extends x {
  c: string;
}
```

What I want is to declare a property that accepts an Array of a mix of y and z Objects, or basically any Object that is an extended Version of x. Is that possible? Perhaps something like this?

```
export interface n {
  d: <T extends x>[];
}
```

Comment: Only objects that extend `x`? Or `x` too?

Comment: Either is fine. But out of interest... what would be the solution if I only wanted Objects that extend x?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, you might have to create a dummy interface like `interface dummy extends x {}` and then use that. Maybe someone else knows of a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export interface n {
  d: Array<x>;
}
```